# How to integrate LUIS in the Waterfall dialog model

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a bot using **SDK v4 version** and in that, I've implemented **Waterfall dialog model**. Now I'm trying to **integrate LUIS** to that dialog model and getting issues there. Can someone help me achieving it

Comment: Please share the code you've tried.  What are the issues you've run into?

Comment: Are you still working on this?